# Why CFC naming system is so weird?

Tags: nomenclature

Why it can't be just as simple as just the number of C, H & F atoms respectively instead of (C - 1), (H+1) & F?

Answer (score 2):

> A special numbering system is to be used for fluorinated alkanes, prefixed with Freon-, R-, CFC- and HCFC-, where the rightmost value indicates the number of fluorine atoms, the next value to the left is the number of hydrogen atoms plus 1, and the next value to the left is the number of carbon atoms less one (zeroes are not stated), and the remaining atoms are chlorine.
>
> Freon-12, for example, indicates a methane derivative (only two numbers) containing two fluorine atoms (the second 2) and no hydrogen ($1 - 1 = 0$). It is therefore $\ce{CCl2F2}$.

(English edition of Wikipedia, [Chlorofluorocarbon#Numbering_system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorofluorocarbon#Numbering_system))

For that the system in part overlaps with R-numbers about media used for *refrigerants*, I speculate one wanted a description condensed, meaningful internationally, accessible across multiple languages, and for multiple professions. Arguably, this is a consent (e.g., Freon 112 about tetrachloro-1,2-difluoroethane, and Freon 112a about tetrachloro-1,1-difluoroethane the table compiles) with some limitations, and yet was/is powerful *enough* among the intended audience as an alias *easy* to recognize:

[image]

(image credit: English edition of Wikipedia, [refrigerant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refrigerant))

(We chemists are not better in this regard naming a liquid ["petrol ether"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petroleum_ether), though there is no oxygen among the alkane molecules in question.)